# How to add two flutter projects and core library (package dart plugin) in the same window

Tags: function, dart, flutter

I want to create two flutter applications which share a lot of functions through another flutter package (core package).

I want to open two projects and core package in the same window using Android Studio.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can have this structure:

```
/core - a pure dart code, with dependencies, etc
/app1 - in this pubspec.yaml, just put: as dependencie:
    core: 
      path: ../core
/app2
    core: 
      path: ../core
```

This way, you are referencing you core project as app1 and app2 dependencie.

Look this project as example: https://github.com/roughike/inKino . 
It shares `core` project on flutter app and web app.

Comment: I am using andriod studio , so when create dart package(core) , it open in windows which is fine . Now I need to add app1 and app2 as application . When I create new application , it open in separate windows , I need them with same window .